# Populating ul list with index

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble populating a ul li with its index value.

My HTML below.

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

My JS below.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
var indexus = $('li').index();
$('li').each(function(){
$('li').html(indexus);
});
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kuJWc/407/

I want to populate the `li` with its appropriate `li` index value, but I can only end up getting the index value of the latest (in this case 3). How would I go about looping in each index value so that each `li` shows the value of its own index number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do like this:

```
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).index());
});
```

you were adding the index to all the `li`.. so istead of `$(this)` inside of the each, you were using `$('li').` which adds the last value li index to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('li').each(function(){   // iterate through each `li`
    var $li = $(this);       // get the current `li` element
    var index = $li.index(); // get the current `li` index
    $li.html(index);         // set the `li`'s html to the index value
  });
});
```

I added some comments to help you understand what each step does, I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var indexus = $('li');
    for (var i = 0; i <= indexus.length; i++) {
        $(indexus[i]).html(i);
    }
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/1nb22c17/) it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of the ul's children and then iterate over each of the children with something like this:

```
var arr = $('ul').children();

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  $(arr[i]).html(i);
}
```